# Making onTouchEvent play nice with OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, gridview, textview, touch-event, onitemclicklistener

I have implemented a custom `TextView` class so that I can handle touch and touch release events for `TextView`s that exist in a `GridView`. I got that to work well. However, I also had set up `OnItemClickListener` for the `GridView` so I can handle that event and run code in the main fragment - on click wouldn't be appropriate to handle in the custom `TextView` class itself. But now that I have implemented both of those they are conflicting and the event to release the touch is not being triggered now.

How do I allow these gesture events to both be triggered - `onTouchEvent` in a custom class and `OnItemClickListener` in the GridView, without losing some of the action events?

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //handle click
        }
});
```

In the custom TextView class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //handle touch and release events only
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 
        //handle touch down
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
            || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
            || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL
            || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE
            || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL) {
        //handle touch release
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

With this code, when I tap and release a `TextView`, the touch down code is run, the `OnItemClickListener` is called in the `GridView`, but `onTouchEvent` is not called again so the touch release event is not handled.

If I change `onTouchEvent` to the following, the touch and touch release is properly handled but `OnItemClickListener` is not called:

```
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        //handle touch down
        return true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
            || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL
            || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE
            || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL) {
        //handle touch release
        return false;
    }

    return true;
```

Comment: Return `false` in the `onTouchEvent()` method.

Comment: @MikeM. that worked but then the touch release events weren't triggered, so I just duplicated the code in the on click and on long click to run after those were triggered

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I didn't think that through. It'd be more involved than that. If you've got it working, I'd say stick with it.

Comment: @MikeM. Returning false after touch down and true after touch release (up, cancel, outside, scroll) and false otherwise doesn't obtain the desired behavior. If I click, touch down and then on item click is called, but on release is not called. Tapping and holding then moving the finger up scrolls the GridView and on release is not called. I can run the on release code in on click/long click but I can't handle the last case - scrolling.

Comment: Ok, sorry I've been misleading, but I'm not at my IDE, and I'm just trying to reason this out. If the problem is the click isn't firing, you can call `performClick()` in `ACTION_UP`. Long click, I have no clue at the moment. I'll try to do some testing later.

Comment: @MikeM. No worries, I appreciate the help. `performClick()` doesn't trigger the on item click event.

Comment: Well, I can't provide nice advice, but a different idea perhaps - android input events work like "producer-consumer" pattern. TextView that You have inside Grid consumes an input (returning true) thus it is only recipient of resulting "release" event. If You return false - You are saying that this object is not recipient of this input message, nor it should receive following/connected ones. If I was to suggest a solution, i'd try to separate gridview and textview code. From textview i'd call something like notify() to update "adapter" contents...