# onClick is not called for TextView that implements onTouchEvent

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, touch-event

I need to handle touch events as well as click events in a custom class that extends `TextView`. But the problem is, `onClick` is never called. What's the problem here?

First I call the super's implementation which is supposed to allow `onClick` to work, then I return `true` because if you return `false` then it won't handle future events.

```
public class ButtonTextView extends TextView implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            highlightButton();
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("test", "click"); //never gets called!
    }
}
```

Comment: Try returning `super.onTouchEvent()` rather than calling `super.onTouchEvent()`, throwing out the result, and returning `true`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Nope, actually if I comment out `onTouchEvent` then `onClick` still doesn't get called. Am I missing something?

Comment: If that's all the code there is, you're missing a call to `setOnClickListener()`. Just because you implement `View.OnClickListener` does not mean that you will get called with `onClick()`. I missed that in my original comment -- sorry!

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, where should that be done at? I have a grid view full of these text views. Setting `gridView.setOnItemClickListener` didn't do the trick, neither is called.

Comment: "Setting gridView.setOnItemClickListener didn't do the trick, neither is called" -- no, but your `OnItemClickListener` that you supplied to `setOnItemClickListener()` should be called. IMHO, having a widget (`ButtonTextView`) handle its own high-order UI events (`onClick()`) is a separation-of-concerns code smell. Something that is serving as a controller (e.g., activity or fragment) should handle those events. That being said, you would need to call `setOnClickListener()` on the `ButtonTextView` itself, though whether you can do that in a `ButtonTextView` constructor safely, I cannot say.

Comment: @CommonsWare This wasn't my first approach to solving the problem. It was suggested I handle it all in the `ButtonTextView` so that's how I ended up at this point. I would love to handle `onItemClick` in the grid view and long click too but those implementations don't get called, or it breaks part of the touch handling, when I need to handle all the touch events in the `ButtonTextView`. This was my first approach which I never got working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083249/allowing-onitemclicklistener-to-work-with-custom-textview